# How do I get Dangerdeep to work?

Tags: 10.04, games

Has anyone been able to get [Danger From The Deep](http://dangerdeep.sourceforge.net/) (Dangerdeep) to work under Ubuntu 10.04 for longer than 5 minutes or so without crashing & hanging up???

The graphics are superb & it looks like it would be a great game, if it would just work!!!

I have downloaded the "latest" files from Source Forge site, but still no luck.

Comment: Yay, they finally have a new release!  The last one from a few years ago wasn't really playable.

Comment: Bah, I also have it hang up after about 5 minutes on 10.10.  So far it seems to happen when using the binoculars screen.

Comment: doesn't seem to make any difference what screen using--it just doesn't work for longer than 5-6 minutes--see last my comment below...

Answer (score 2):

You're (maybe) in luck, it appears as though someone is packaging Dangerdeep in a PPA here (last update was in November):

- https://launchpad.net/~aegirxx-googlemail/+archive/dftd-latest
- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

Here's the quick and dirty way in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:aegirxx-googlemail/dftd-latest
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dangerdeep-latest
```

The upstream page does say that the game is in Alpha, so it might be one of those things where you'll need to report the failures to the developers, maybe they're looking for testers!

The binary to launch it is put in `/usr/bin/dangerdeep`. The deb appears to be missing a .desktop file, which is why it doesn't appear in the menu. This should be filed as a bug report with dangerdeep so that it's easier for users to find it.

Comment: By the way this game looks awesome.

Comment: thanx Jorge...I will try this & see what happens

Comment: well....it appeared to work, but I can't find any Dangerdeep directory now...

Comment: when I loaded it from Sourceforge it put the directory on my desktop...doing a ls from a terminal doesn't show any dangerdeep directory...same thing with a search for "dangerdeep"...where would it have put it???

Comment: thanx once again Jorge....it seems to be working...for now...will do a longer test when I get time...I will file a bug report on

Comment: bug report report on #dangerdeep IRC channel

Comment: I talked to 1 of the DEVS today on IRC #dangerdeep channel & sent him a stack trace of my SIGSEGV error...he said that he will try to find time to get it fixed...we'll see won't we...

Answer (score 0):

On my Ubuntu 10.04 Danger Deep run very well.
I've installed Dangerdeep.deb, dangerdeep_latest, and dangerdeep_data.
And renewest my videocard driver.
But dangerdeep getting crash from dangerdeep binary file.